# Как ускорить этот код? Python

Tags: python

Есть такой код:

```
s1 = 'dfgwjkgofdgrghdflsdgdfd'
s2 = 'world'

w = []
for x in s2:
    if x in s1:
        w.append(x)
        s1 = s1.replace(x, '', 1)

print(True if ''.join(w) == s2 else False)
```

Он проверяет можно ли из букв первого слова собрать второе слово. При этом учитывает количество букв. Например, в данном случае выдаст **True**. А если **s2** заменить на **woorld**, то выдаст **False**, так как в **s1** всего одна буква **o**.

Он работает, но CodeWars его не принимает, так как выполнение слишком долгое для огромных строк. Я предполагаю, что можно использовать count вместо replace, но не совсем понимаю логику как это реализовать. А может это возможно с помощью iter, next... В общем, вопрос - как ускорить этот код или написать аналогичный, но более быстрый?

Comment: одно из решений Hashmap - построить словарь из имеющегося набора букв и пройтись по s2 уменьшая значения из этого словаря.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter


s1 = 'dfgwjkgofdgrghdflsdgdfd'
s2 = 'world'

print(Counter(s1) >= Counter(s2))
```

Для Питона до версии 3.10 код придётся изменить:

```
c1 = Counter(s1)
c2 = Counter(s2)
print(all(c1[k] >= v for k, v in c2.items()))
```

Comment: @splash58, спасибо. Поправил.